# Pipe and Maps in Angular

Tags: angular, dictionary, pipe

I am trying to use multiple map() inside one .Pipe() statement, but it is not working. It does not give me error but it also does not give me the desired output. here is the sample code.

```
makePurchase$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(makePurchase),
    mergeMap(({ elementId }) =>
      this.simStateService.makePurchase(elementId)
        .pipe(
          map(() => calculateBalance()),
          map(() => makePurchaseSuccess({elementId})),
          catchError((err) => {
            console.log('THERE WAS AN ERROR');
            console.error('error from the thing', err);
            return makePurchase;
          })
        )
    )
  ));
```

I want to be able to pass both of those map but only one or the other works. I want to be able to call akePurchaseSuccess({elementId})) after the purchase is successful and then calculate balance.

Comment: You probably want to post the functions you’re calling..

Comment: Agreed, we need the functions you are calling inside your `map()` calls. Conceptually, multiple maps are absolutely fine inside one `pipe()`. Though, what I am wondering about, both of your `map()` functions are not taking an argument for their callback. Are you sure you don't want `tap()` instead of `map()`?

Comment: You're probably aiming for a `tap` operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue a while ago, in fact I think your should really check if you're really always transmitting Observable objects between your map calls.

This is a rxjs map function, not the built in javascript one: You need to apply it on Observables.

I hope this helped you a bit.